# How to allow specific characters with Laravel validation

Tags: laravel

I am on Laravel 5.6
Working on a comment box's text validation. I know about some predefined validation rules in laravel like Alpha_dash. But I want validation rule just like below.

- Alphanumeric
- Dash and Underscore
- **Dot and Commas**
- **Inverted Commas and Double Inverted Commas**
  [image]
  Anyone know, How to achieve this kind of validation?

Comment: use this validation rule https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex

Comment: I had already checked it, but I am new to laravel. Can you explain to me or show me some example?

Comment: see in your project `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php` file line 1764

Answer (score 2):

This will be the rule [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-regex), in this case:

`regex:[a-zA-Z0-9.,'"]+`

[image]

Here is a demo of the regex with explaination: https://regex101.com/r/MlmyHm/1/

Comment: I tried this one also, but problem is that this is validating only first character of my text. if I put invalid characters after some alphanumeric text, this validator passed without testing for the next

Comment: What if you add the `/g` (global) modifier? `regex:^[a-zA-Z0-9.,'"]+$/g`

Comment: when is add /g error pop up " preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g' "

Comment: than just the anchors ^ and $ without /g?

Comment: then validation checking for an only first character means if the text has the first character > then it will fail validation n shows me an error on my view perfectly. but if text consist > at some other position then this allow me to pass validation

Comment: please refer screenshot i just attached.

Comment: you don't escape your singlequote

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: `'required:regex:/[A-Za-z0-9-,.()"\'?]+/g'` see the backslash?

Comment: I pasted it but now it is allowing everything.

Comment: I'm affraid I don't know for now than

Comment: is there any other way for validation?

Comment: This should work and just needs debugging, you should not immediatly try another solution and give up

Comment: @ImZedi is wright. using your  'address' => "required|".'regex:/[A-Za-z0-9-,.()/?]+/g', rule it is being allow everything.